LED driver inductor heating
I have a LED driver based on AP3019, here's the schematics:

The LEDs its feeding are 4s2p white LCD backlight, rated 12V@40mA, the input voltage is 5V.
According to the datasheet, AP3019's switching frequency is 1.2 MHz.
Inductor characteristics are:




MAX
TYP





Isat, A
0.60
0.88
saturation current


Ihrms, A
0.83
0.90
heat rating current


Dcr, Ω
0.345
0.265
DC resistance


L, uH

10±20%
100kHz@1V


S.R.F., MHz

42
Self-resonant freq



I'm facing a problem of inductor heating quite a lot. If set to maximum brightness (PWM@100% or 3.3V on CTRL pin) - it gets hot. Since I have no thermal camera - can’t say how much, however its hard to hold a finger on it for too long, so I guess 50°C or more.
What could be a reason for it? I could only assume its either a high DCR value or a switching/ripple current being too high for that part?
P.S. There's nothing about inductor selection within driver's datasheet, and I'm not too familiar with boost converters to know about inductor parameters influence on the schematic.
It only states

A constant frequency 1.2MHz PWM control scheme is employed in
this IC, which means tiny external components can be used.
Specifically, 1mm tall inductor and 0.22uF output capacitor for a
typical application is sufficient.


There's no input or output capacitor shown?

Input cap is present (on another schematic part). And output cap was added after PCB prototype production since it was omitted on design.

Ah, okay. Don't suppose you have oscilloscope waveforms (input, SW, output)(preferably >100MHz bandwidth)?

What does your board layout look like?  The output capacitor is an essential component, omitting it sounds like you may have problems with the layout.

Nope, have no scope (yet). I've made a stupid mistake forgetting an output cap. The new board revision should arrive shortly, with the cap already attached and inductor changed to the one with a less DCR, more close to the recommended one from the datasheet.

So I have found out that it is controller heating, not inductor.
For the older PCBs - one was due to faulty led controller itself, stopped working at all after a few days, and others - 2 out of 4 are working ok, another 2 - working with heating. Also old ones heats a lot without a LED attached.
Maybe the failure was caused by powering it without an output capacitord and LED attached.
A new PCB revision batch with a bigger inductor (and capacitors preinstalled, thanks @user1850479 @tim-williams) - almost no heating at all.

The recommended inductor is stated (in the datasheet) as:

SUMIDA CDRH5D28R-220NC or equivalent

The manufacturer's data, including temperature and saturation curves, for that inductor is located here
If you want to use some other inductor, you should compare and ensure that the specifications are equivalent or better, particularly the saturation and temperature specs.

yep, I've seen that recommended one. Picked some similar, however smaller part (higher DCR, but the same rated/saturation). Also referred to the makerfabs and ESP32box schematics (those have the same LED drivers). Seems 250 mOhm is too much, will have to sacrifice the size selecting the inductor with a lower DCR.

First, we need to clarify the temperature requirements for the inductor in the project. For example, in an LED product I worked on before, the temperature requirement for the inductor was that under full power operation in a 25°C environment, the temperature should not exceed 80°C. The design must be tailored to specific application scenarios.
Of course, we also have methods to reduce the inductor temperature, as you mentioned. We can select an inductor with a lower DCR. Based on energy conservation, increasing the input voltage can reduce the average current through the inductor, thus reducing heat generation. Using a larger-sized inductor can also help.
On the PCB, you can lay copper under the inductor and create thermal vias (although typically, there should be a void under the inductor, but electronic design must balance the design objectives). You can also add a heatsink. If space is limited, you can attach a small piece of thermal silicone to the inductor's surface to tightly fit the case. Additionally, you can conduct experiments, such as increasing the input and output capacitors, to see the effects.
By the way, this schematic looks like it was created using a Chinese-developed EDA software!

Is there any limitations on using Easy-EDA here (on StackExchange)? I wasn't aware of it
